# Why does an empty wWinMain() open my mouse settings?

Tags: c++, winapi

I wrote a code snippet which includes `<windows.h>`, has the `wWinMain()` function with its normal arguments, and it just has `return 0` in the function's body.

Now, when I compile it with `g++ main.cpp -o main -municode; main`, it opens my Mouse Settings window out of nowhere. Why is it working like this? I don't get it.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    return 0;
}
```

I expected it does nothing, but now it opens my Mouse Settings window - HOW?

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @KenWhite I believe the image was to show the mouse settings applet that runs as a result if issuing `main` in Powershell.

Comment: Closed for the wrong reason.  All the necessary information is in there.  Should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Clifford: If so, then all that should have been shown in the image is the mouse settings applet window, not the OP's entire desktop and IDE.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't disagree, why are you telling me?

Comment: @Clifford: I was responding to the comment you made addressed to me. I guess I'm telling you for the same reason you felt the need to tell me.

Comment: @KenWhite : you were making a different point, one I wouldn't disagree with, and is a comment for the OP not me. Apologies if that was not clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Powershell, commands must either specify the path of the executable, or the executable must be in a path included in the `PATH` environment variable.

To run an executable `main.exe` in the *current working directory*, the command must be: `.\main`.

When you issue `main` on its own, you are launching the Control Panel applet: `C:\Windows\System32\main.cpl`.

Comment: Thank u, it explained it <3, the main.exe instead of the main in the g++ command isnt relevant tho

Comment: @fluffy perhaps not, but the whole g++ command was irrelevant, and the question is off topic. Running main.cpl intentionally or otherwise is not a programming issue.  Recognising that that is what happened is not a programming issue. Knowing how Powershell works is not a programming issue.